# Git ignore file

Tags: git, github

Where should we create **git ignore** file? and why my **git ignore** not showing to me? How can I reach to this file?

I'm making it in my working folder but it is not showing to me and when I'm trying to create it is showing that this file exists already.

Answer (score 1):

A .gitignore file is usually placed in the repository’s root directory. However, you can create multiple .gitignore files in different subdirectories in your repository. The patterns in the .gitignore files are matched relative to the directory where the file resides.

Patterns defined in the files that reside in lower-level directories (sub-directories) have precedence over those in higher-level directories.

On Mac and Linux, files starting with '.' are hidden by default and so the tools you are using to view them need to be set to make them visible. On the command line, this is the difference between `ls` and `ls -a`.